# start inadyn on boot

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-10.04

How can I setup `inadyn` to load on Ubuntu startup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the command required to run at startup to /etc/rc.local.  Ensure it is executable and in root's PATH.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are talking about the [DynDNS updater](http://www.inatech.eu/inadyn/readme.html)... and you are planning on running it in daemon mode, I'd say hulbs9nw is spot on.

It appears as though it supports console mode, also, which means you could potentially run it from cron as well.